# Gravity Forms Multi Page Losing POST value

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I have a complex Gravity Form built, it has 10 pages. I am using fields to build a "string" that I then match to a CPT name to get meta data from to display a selection, based on user choices in the form.

One field I have is not holding its value in POST. I can see it when I select the value on the page, then when I click to next page the value is still there. However, after two pages the value ( and field ) disappear from POST.

This is the function I have put together that builds my product string.

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_12', 'display_choice_result' );

function display_choice_result( $form ) {
$current_page = GFFormDisplay::get_current_page( $form['id'] );
$html_content = "";
$prod_string = "";

if ( $current_page >= 10 ) {
    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
        // Check for a class of "product-builder-item" on the field
        // I use this as another way to denote what fields to add to string
        if ( strpos( $field->cssClass, 'product-builder-item' ) === false ) {
            continue;
        }

        //gather form data to save into html field (Field ID 14 on Form ID 12)
        //exclude page break and any hidden fields
        if ( $field->id != 14 && $field->type != 'page' ) {
            $is_hidden = RGFormsModel::is_field_hidden( $form, $field, array() );
            $populated = rgpost( 'input_' . $field->id );

            // Make sure the field we are getting the value from is not hidden and has a value
            if ( !$is_hidden && $populated !='' ) {
                $html_content .= '<li>' . $field->label . ': ' . rgpost( 'input_' . $field->id ) . '</li>';
                $prod_string .= rgpost( 'input_' . $field->id );
            }
        }
    }
    // Do a bunch of stuff here with the $prod_string variable
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
}
return $form;
}
```

Screenshots showing the POST disappearing..The POST field in question is `input_22` with a value of **18000**

This is one page after I choose from the field

[image]

This is *two* pages after,

[image]

Anyone run into this before or have any idea why it would be disappearing?

Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Running into a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exact issue as you described. I realized that a jQuery function was interfering with Gravity Form process. The jQuery function was set to change a zip code field from type text to tel so the number pad would open up on mobile devices. This is what was causing my issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please post your code as well (before and after), which will help to determine if your answer is relevant for the question. (You can edit your answer)